# Creating a dynamic DRL file with multiple "when", "then", and "end" sections and setting values in the "then" section dynamically

Tags: java

private String applyRuleTemplate(DiscountObject discountObject, List ruleSets) throws Exception {
ObjectDataCompiler objectDataCompiler = new ObjectDataCompiler();

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (RuleSet ruleSet : ruleSets) {

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("ruleSet", ruleSet.getRuleGroupString());
        data.put("discountObject", discountObject.getClass().getName());
        data.put("outCome", ruleSet.getOutCome());

        // dataList = Arrays.asList(data);
        dataList.add(data);
    }
    String strRet = objectDataCompiler.compile(dataList,
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ruleSet-template.drl"));
    return strRet;
}
```

KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
StatelessKieSession statelessKieSession = kieContainer.getKieBase().newStatelessKieSession();

```
     DiscountOutComeObject discountOutcomeObject = new DiscountOutComeObject(); 
            statelessKieSession.getGlobals().set("ruleSet", ruleSet);
            statelessKieSession.getGlobals().set("discountOutcomeObject", discountOutcomeObject);
            statelessKieSession.getGlobals().set("map", map);
            statelessKieSession.execute(Arrays.asList(discountObject,discountOutcomeObject));
        
    discountOutcomeObject = (DiscountOutComeObject) map.get("discountOutcomeObject");
```

I have been able to generate the DRL file dynamically using a template and populate the "when" section with the desired conditions. However, I'm facing difficulties in setting values dynamically in the "then" section of the ruleSet.
My template file